# how to import project from another drive on intelliJ in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, linux, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04, intellij-15

[only computer path is loaded but does not show any drive or partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqPeC.png)How to import android project form another drive to intelliJ in ubuntu 16.04?

Hi,

I have install IntelliJ idea on my ubuntu 16.04 recently. It is working fine but it just does not import android or other projects from another partition that is I partitioned my computer Hard drive. So is it possible to import from another drive or partition? How to import project from another partition or drive

Comment: Do you mean that it's impossible to select other partition in "File | Open..."? Do you get any error/warning messages?

Comment: Yes It is not showing the particular partition

Comment: No I don't get any error or warning message instead it does not give option to select that drive.

Comment: What is the full path to your project if you locate it from command line?

Comment: /media/Abhi/Study/other/android/android_project/My Application-    This is the path shown on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to open the file/folder in yor explorer (your external disk)

Then rigth click on "open in terminal"

In the terminal you will be able to see a path like "/media/{USERNAME}/{DISK_NAME}"

Copy that path and paste it on IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Go to file-> Open in Intellij.
Then drag the project folder to that window and it will automatically show that in intellij.
Hit the Open button.